# Convert java string into keyvalue pair

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I have java String like below

```
String mStr = "Key1:value1   key2:value2   key3:value3"
```

How to convert/add this string in to java Hash map..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this regex with 2 captured groups:

```
(\w+):(\w+)
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):(\\w+)");
```

Then iterate the results using `while (matcher.find())` and grab both captured groups.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY1zX0/1)